# how to print the results of a getter method in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk

I have programmed the following accessing method:

```
name
    "comment stating purpose of message"
    ^name.

age
    "comment stating purpose of message"
    ^age.

name:aName
    name:=aName.

age: aNumber
    age:=aNumber.
```

The problem is that when I do the following in the transcript or playground in Pharo:

```
|p|
p:=Person new.
p name:'Milla'.
p age: 20.

p name.
p age.
Transcript show:p name.
```

It only displays the message:

```
"Transript"
self
```

in the playground

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with: "displays the message self"? According to your code the transcript should show the result of `p name`

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're selecting your text in the playground and doing "inspect it", and then seeing what comes up in the inspector, which is the result of your last message send, i.e. `show:` was sent to `Transcript` and `Transcript` returned `self`, by default. You don't seem to be looking at a Transcript at all.

What you want to do instead is actually *open* a Transcript window (`World menu` > `Tools` > `Transcript`), then instead of doing "inspect it" in the playground, just use "do it", and ignore what the result of your message send is - the actual result will be displayed in the transcript, not in the inspector.